# Deadlock in SQL Server 2008 | INSERT (from application, EF) & SELECT (from stored procedure) statement working simultaneously

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, deadlock, database-deadlocks

Program to insert into my 2 tables is written through Entity Framework and to SELECT the data is through a STORED PROC at SQL SERVER level. There is a point when SELECT and INSERT is getting done at the same time **simultaneously**. And when hitting that point, I got the below error:

**Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked on resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.**

How can I get rid of this DEADLOCK problem here? Need the best way to solve it.

**Option 1:** Implementing NOLOCK? What would be the PROS and CONS here for it?
**Option 2:** IF there is any way to exceed the DEADLOCK wait time so that it can wait for the resource for a longer time than usually it does? If yes, then HOW?
**Option 3:** Suggest Me?

Thanks,
Rahuul Dutta

Comment: I am always pushed at work to use nolock with everything. I was experiencing an issue, like the one you are now, and using with (Nolock) on the from statement and joins usually fixes that. Also, you propbably do not want to exceed deadlock wait time.... You just never want to get in a deadlock situation. The deadlock will also usually never end.... Why it is a DeadLock

Comment: Actually, there is no such a thing as a 'deadlock timeout'; a deadlock occurs or it doesn't but it's not something that you can wait for to disappear! Also, please do not use `NOLOCK` unless you are extremely sure what you're doing. If you're in doubt, then think about how you would feel using the `READUNCOMMITTED` hint.

Answer (score 3):

A deadlock cannot be cured by increasing lock timeout. The resources are locked in such a way that it cannot be resolved by itself, regardless of how much time you can give it. A special background process in SQL Server, a deadlock monitor, periodically (rather often, actually) runs and if it identifies a deadlock it kills the 'lighter' transaction immediatelly.

The deadlocks are usually dealt with in one of several ways: by providing an alternative data access path for the `SELECT` query (ie adding a mnnclustered index), minimizing the transaction duration (by better indexing, again), or using one of snapshot isolation levels.

The least effort solution here will be setting the `read committed snapshot` isolation level. This way the `SELECT` query will not issue any shared locks on data, but still read only the committed data, which is a huge plus over using the `NOLOCK` hint (or `read uncommitted` isolation level).

Answer (score 1):

You can change your transaction isolation level. Best option for deadlocks would be `snapshot isolation` i think. If you cannot turn this option on in your server or if you run into I/O issues, `read committed` should still prevent deadlocks from read/write dependencies. Make sure that you don't run into anomalies, read committed will allow non-repeatable reads and phantom reads.

Comment: Read commited (the locking variety) won't help here.

Comment: Why is that? If you have R1(x),W2(Y),W1(Y),W2(X) it's a deadlock if R1(x) will be held until EOT but it isn't if it is released after the read.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks a lot for your precious answers!

**With the help of your answers, some research and a call with Microsoft DBA team, I have got the following solution.**

**Solution:** To implement this solution we have to change the database property to Read Committed Snapshot. This will help the Select statements in avoiding the blocks in case of locks by other sessions on the same table.
- To cater this solution the database will create a snapshot of the data in tempdb. Therefore we must have sufficient space in tempdb. Also if possible we must shift the tempdb to a new disk to split the I/O. This will improve the performance.

- The following kb article helps in enabling Read Committed Snapshot property of the database:
  [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175095(v=SQL.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175095%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx)
- Alternately we can change this property through SSMS by right clicking the database---options---Miscellaneous----Is Read Committed Snapshot On. We have to change the value of this property to TRUE.
- We do not have to restart the server to enable this property however we must note that 'When setting the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT option, only the connection executing the ALTER DATABASE command is allowed in the database. There must be no other open connection in the database until ALTER DATABASE is complete. The database does not have to be in single-user mode.'
- This means we need a small amount of downtime from the application side.

**Hope the MOM above would help you all too. :)**

Thanks,

Rahuul Dutta